# What would be the best way to create a calender using tkinter?

Tags: python, ms-access, tkinter

I'm working on a project for school and it's a system where staff can enter their name then input their holiday dates and this will be displayed on a calender. Administrators will also be able to add holiday restrictions, remove holidays and also add/remove staff members. 
I'm using tkinter for this system and I have an access database that will store the staff members, holiday dates etc.
What would be the best way to create a calendar using tkinter? It would need to display holidays on the date markings and potentially the name of who would be on holiday on that date.
Any suggestions in general would be appreciated too :) Thank you :)
Here is my current if it helps:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import END, PhotoImage
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)
LARGER_FONT = ("Comic Sans MS", 20)
TITLE_FONT = ("Verdana", 15)


class HolSys(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, AdminSelection, StaffAddition, HolidayRemoval, HelpPage, RestrictionAddition):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.winfo_toplevel().title("Holiday System")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Starter", font=LARGE_FONT).grid(
            row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Holiday Input", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(
            PageOne), width=14, height=2).grid(row=2, column=1)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Admin", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(
            PageTwo), width=14, height=2).grid(row=2, column=2)
        buttonHelp = tk.Button(self, text="?", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(
            HelpPage), font=LARGER_FONT, width=1, height=1).grid(row=0, column=0)


class HelpPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="Help", font=TITLE_FONT).grid()
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.grid()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        month = tk.StringVar(self)
        year = tk.StringVar(self)

        monthList = [
            'pick a month',
            'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr',
            'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',
            'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
        ]
        yearList = ['2019', '2020', '2021', '2022']
        month31 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
                   "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"]
        month30 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
                   "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"]
        month29 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
                   "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29"]
        month28 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",
                   "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28"]
        MonthsWith31D = ['Jan', 'Mar', 'May', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Oct', 'Dec']
        MonthsWith30D = ['Apr', 'Jun', 'Sep', 'Nov']
        LeapYears = ['2020', '2024', '2028']
        Mvar = tk.StringVar(self)
        Mvar.set("January")  # initial value for month
        Dvar = tk.StringVar(self)
        Dvar.set("1st")  # initial value for date
        Yvar = tk.StringVar(self)
        Yvar.set("2019")  # initial value for year
        s_month = month31

        date = tk.OptionMenu(self, Dvar, *s_month)
        date.pack()  # creates the optionmenu button for dates

        def MonthSelEvent(*args):
            if month.get() == 'Feb':
                date['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
                if year.get() in LeapYears:
                    date['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
                    for x in month29:
                        date['menu'].add_command(
                            label=x, command=tk._setit(Dvar, x))
                        # set it to first/default for selection
                        Dvar.set(month29[0])
                    else:
                        date['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
                        for x in month28:
                            date['menu'].add_command(
                                label=x, command=tk._setit(Dvar, x))
                            # set it to first/default for selection
                            Dvar.set(month28[0])
            elif month.get() in MonthsWith31D:
                date['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
                for x in month31:
                    date['menu'].add_command(
                        label=x, command=tk._setit(Dvar, x))
                    # set it to first/default for selection
                    Dvar.set(month31[0])
            elif month.get() in MonthsWith30D:
                date['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
                for x in month30:
                    date['menu'].add_command(
                        label=x, command=tk._setit(Dvar, x))
                    # set it to first/default for selection
                    Dvar.set(month30[0])
            else:
                pass  # covers the 'select a month' option

        monthSelect = tk.OptionMenu(self, month, *monthList,
                                    command=MonthSelEvent).pack()
        # trace on the variable that is changed
        month.trace("w", MonthSelEvent)
        yearSelect = tk.OptionMenu(
            self, year, *yearList, command=MonthSelEvent).pack()
        year.trace('w', MonthSelEvent)
        year.set(yearList[0])
        month.set(monthList[0])  # set initial value of dropdown
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Admin", font=LARGE_FONT)
        L1 = tk.Label(self, text="Password").grid(row=0)
        e1 = tk.Entry(self, show="*")
        e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

        def callback(event=None):
            if e1.get() == "john":
                controller.show_frame(AdminSelection)
                e1.delete(0, END)
                e1.insert(0, "")
            else:
                L2.config(text="incorrect")
                e1.delete(0, END)
                e1.insert(0, "")
        L2 = tk.Label(self, text="")
        L2.grid()
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=callback).grid()
        self.bind_all("<Return>", callback)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).grid()


class AdminSelection(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="sweet").grid()
        tk.Button(self, text="Staff\n Removal/Addition",
                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StaffAddition)).grid(column=0)

        tk.Button(self, text="Holiday Restriction/Addition",
                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame(RestrictionAddition)).grid(column=1)

        tk.Button(self, text="Holiday\n Removal", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(
            HolidayRemoval)).grid(column=1, row=1)

        tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(
            StartPage)).grid(column=3)


class StaffAddition(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="Staff Addition").grid()
        tk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(
            AdminSelection)).grid(column=3)


class RestrictionAddition(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="Restriction Addition").grid()
        tk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(
            AdminSelection)).grid(column=3)


class HolidayRemoval(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text="Holiday Removal").grid()
        tk.Button(self, text="Back", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(
            AdminSelection)).grid(column=3)

app = HolSys()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: [tkcalendar](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar) - [example](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [tkcalendar](https://github.com/j4321/tkcalendar)

If you run [example](https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/example.html) from documentation then you can see calendar

[image]

and with events

[image]

or to select date

[image]